# Heroku + Rails Error: "Entering the V8 API without proper locking in place"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, v8

```
ActionView::Template::Error (HandleScope::HandleScope: Entering the V8 API without proper locking in place
  (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
    3: <head>
    4: <title>Reminders</title>
    5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    6: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/bg_<%= current_or_guest_user.background %>.css" />
    9: </head>  
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1680303581718722157_49016340'
```

Any idea what's causing this?  I'm new to ruby, rails, and heroku, so there's a lot of things I might be doing wrong.

If I get rid of the javascript_include_tag my app runs, but then of course I get no javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecJS 1.1.3 implements locking for V8. This should solve your issues with JS minified.

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/commit/a48bc7c7ad03bec4f8abde1fa76c95cccc59f818#comments

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by commenting the uglifier gem out of my GemFile.

Comment: not ultimately a great solution, but it just saved me when my production site on heroku failed - staging, also on heroku, was fine.  the real problem, for me at least, has something to do with the compression (because of v8/execjs/therubyrunner/something)... and I still have to work that out. But this is a very nice temporary bandaid and not to be scoffed at.  Don't forget to turn off compression in your production.rb!